# How to change image thumb in aiogram

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

The bot receives audio from the user and needs to convert the audio image and send it back to the user

i got the id of the first audio

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['audio'], state=None)
async def get_music(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        audio_id = message.audio.file_id
        chat_id = message.chat.id
        data['audio_id'] = audio_id
        data['chat_id'] = chat_id

        await message.answer("send photo...")
        await GetState.image.set()
```

and then i got the image id

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=GetState.image)
async def send_audio_with_thumb(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        audio_id = data['audio_id']
        chat_id = data['chat_id']
        image_file_id = message.photo[-1].file_id

        await bot.send_audio(chat_id=chat_id, audio=audio_id, thumb=image_file_id)
    await state.finish()
```

then i sent them via send_audio command but the audio image didn't change